# Conditional left join if previous join was null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table 'Identifier' which is in one to many relation with other tables.
Other tables (10 tables) have foregin key to table 'Identifier'. FK may be null.

For each row in table 'Identifier' I need to know if record is in relation with any other table.

I could write something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM IDENTIFIER
LEFT JOIN TABLE1 T1 on T1.IDENTIFIER_ID = IDENTIFIER.ID
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2 on T2.IDENTIFIER_ID = IDENTIFIER.ID
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 T3 on T3.IDENTIFIER_ID = IDENTIFIER.ID
LEFT JOIN TABLE4 T4 on T4.IDENTIFIER_ID = IDENTIFIER.ID
LEFT JOIN TABLE5 T5 on T5.IDENTIFIER_ID = IDENTIFIER.ID
...
```

But if first left join (to table Table1) wasn't null - I would like to skip other left joins for performance reasons.
Tables from 1 to 10 have milions of records and I wouldn't like to join them if not necessary.

Comment: *"But if first left join (to table Table1) wasn't null - I would like to skip other left joins for performance reasons."* You can't. You can't have a "dynamic" join in SQL Server. The fact that you need to do something like this infers a design flaw in truth, and that is likely the real problem you should be fixing.

Comment: I have had this situation before, and utilised a second column to indicate the `type` of the `identifier`.  In the join syntax I then put `... FROM t LEFT JOIN x ON type_col = 1 AND x.identifier = t.identifier LEFT JOIN y ON type_col = 2 AND y.identifier = t.identifier ...`. Still not ideal but prevents spurious joins where the IDs clash. I should add that I inherited the existing design and was not permitted to make signfiicant structural changes, hence the 'hack'

Comment: Joining tables 1 to 10 shouldn't adversely affect performance if they have appropriate indexes on their `IDENTIFIER_ID` columns.

Comment: You could try something like LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2 on T2.IDENTIFIER_ID = IDENTIFIER.ID AND T1.IDENTIFIER_ID IS NULL ..  Although I would suggest a different design if it is causing perf issues, which it shouldn't if well indexed

Comment: @alwaysLearning thank you. What do you mean by approriate indexes?

Comment: @gandRalph thank you. What do you mean by "well indexed"?

Comment: Too large a topic to explain in a comment, all I can suggest is that you learn about indexes and ensure the appropriate ones for your purpose are added to your tables.

Comment: @GandRalph can you recommend some sources? books? a lot of articles around us and hard to decide where to dig

Comment: As you say, there are many, I would suggest any that has good community feedback.  There will be articles on msdn as well I'm sure.

Comment: Best practice says that all foreign key columns should have a corresponding index (i.e.: in the referencing table), not just the index on the candidate/primary key targeted by the foreign key (the referenced table). Adding a nonclustered index to a (32-bit) `int` column with 250 million rows weighs in about 1.3GB, but due to the beauty of B-tree indexes results in a structure that's only 4 levels deep and is much quicker to search than doing a table scan.

Comment: @alwaysLearning how did you calculate that?

Comment: I created one and asked SSMS to display the Index Physical report.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you can try this.

```
SELECT * FROM IDENTIFIER
LEFT JOIN TABLE1 T1 on T1.IDENTIFIER_ID = IDENTIFIER.ID
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2 on T2.IDENTIFIER_ID = IDENTIFIER.ID AND T1.IDENTIFIER_ID IS NULL
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 T3 on T3.IDENTIFIER_ID = IDENTIFIER.ID AND T2.IDENTIFIER_ID IS NULL
LEFT JOIN TABLE4 T4 on T4.IDENTIFIER_ID = IDENTIFIER.ID AND T3.IDENTIFIER_ID IS NULL
LEFT JOIN TABLE5 T5 on T5.IDENTIFIER_ID = IDENTIFIER.ID AND T4.IDENTIFIER_ID IS NULL
```